# How to make an interactable UI in a render texture unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, textures, render

So I'm developing a game that haves a laptop with an screen where is supposed to be all the main features in the game.

I have a separate camera rendering a UI for displaying that UI in the laptop screen. But when I assing the material with the render texture to the screen, the UI isn't interactable anymore. I know that the answer might be obvious, but I couldn't find anything related to the problem.

So, I'm wondering if I can make it interactable.

I'm developing it in unity.

Comment: Why using a render texture at all exactly?

Comment: Because I wanted to make an effect that could make some sort of screen brightning and with a transparent material with the multiply blending mode and a emmisive plane behind it screen I made it. But i have someway solved by adding the plane to the world space.

Comment: Why not rather use [Post-Processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessingOverview.html) for this kind of stuff?